# Google Play Store Announcement of Blocking Apps Using Vulnerable Cordova Versions , eg: Worklight 6.0

Tags: cordova, security, google-play, ibm-mobilefirst

According to this announcement :
[[UPDATED 3/16/2016] IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation Responds to Google Play Store Announcement of Blocking Apps Using Vulnerable Cordova Versions](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/2016/02/16/ibm-mobilefirst-platform-foundation-responds-to-google-play-store-announcement-of-blocking-apps-using-vulnerable-cordova-versions/)

Are the applications which run on Worklight 6.0 concerned ? Because I'm not seeing any fix regarding that version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, 6.0 apps are not affected. Only 6.1 and above.